# AWK - Merging 2 files using common terms in the lines

Tags: awk, merge

I have two files. One is a database that loos like this:

```
GO:0000001      mitochondrion inheritance   P   
GO:0000002      mitochondrial genome maintenance    P   
GO:0000003  GO:0019952 GO:0050876   reproduction    P   
GO:0000005      ribosomal chaperone activity    F   obs
GO:0000006      high affinity zinc uptake transmembrane transporter activity    F   
GO:0000007      low-affinity zinc ion transmembrane transporter activity    F   
GO:0000008  GO:0000013  thioredoxin F   obs
GO:0000009      alpha-1,6-mannosyltransferase activity  F   
GO:0000010      trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity   F   
GO:0000011      vacuole inheritance P   
GO:0000012      single strand break repair  P   
GO:0000014      single-stranded DNA specific endodeoxyribonuclease activity F   
GO:0000015      phosphopyruvate hydratase complex   C   
GO:0000016      lactase activity    F   
GO:0000017      alpha-glucoside transport   P   
GO:0000018      regulation of DNA recombination P   
GO:0000019      regulation of mitotic recombination P
```

And the other one is a file I need to "classify" using said database. It looks like this:

```
gene_id_100000  GO:0004370  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0005524  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0006071  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0006072  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0019563  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100002  GO:0000105  99.42   173 1   0   1   173 256 428 8e-122   357
gene_id_100002  GO:0004399  99.42   173 1   0   1   173 256 428 8e-122   357
gene_id_100002  GO:0008270  99.42   173 1   0   1   173 256 428 8e-122   357
gene_id_100002  GO:0051287  99.42   173 1   0   1   173 256 428 8e-122   357
gene_id_100008  GO:0005737  84.35   147 23  0   7   153 5   151 1e-90    267
gene_id_100008  GO:0008616  84.35   147 23  0   7   153 5   151 1e-90    267
gene_id_100008  GO:0033739  84.35   147 23  0   7   153 5   151 1e-90    267
gene_id_100008  GO:0046857  84.35   147 23  0   7   153 5   151 1e-90    267
gene_id_100017  GO:0003938  71.75   177 50  0   1   177 75  251 6e-86    268
```

As you can see, the common term between the files is the GO:. The only things I care about are the first 2 columns of the file I need to classify (that is, the one with gene_id and the one with GO:) and the description of each GO: term from the database.

The output should look like this (the 2 first columns from the query file followed by the description from the database that matches the GO term from the file):

```
gene_id_100000  GO:0004370  glycerol kinase activity    F
gene_id_100000  GO:0005524  ATP binding F
gene_id_100000  GO:0006071  glycerol metabolic process  P
gene_id_100000  GO:0006072  glycerol-3-phosphate metabolic process  P
gene_id_100000  GO:0019563  glycerol catabolic process  P
gene_id_100002  GO:0000105  histidine biosynthetic process  P
```

Some lines from the database have more than 1 GO: term, so I haven't really been able to get this to work... Also, I don't really know how to work with 2 files at the same time in awk.

Thanks for the help in advance! Hope I explained it clearly.

**Edit for jaypal:** Some of the lines that are missing are the ones that I used as an example for my file:

```
gene_id_100000  GO:0004370  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0005524  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0006071  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0006072  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100000  GO:0019563  69.52   187 57  0   7   193 4   190 1e-90    280
gene_id_100002  GO:0000105  99.42   173 1   0   1   173 256 428 8e-122   357
```

And their corresponding database lines are:

```
GO:0004370      glycerol kinase activity    F
GO:0005524      ATP binding F
GO:0006071      glycerol metabolic process  P
GO:0006072      glycerol-3-phosphate metabolic process  P
GO:0019563      glycerol catabolic process  P
GO:0000105      histidine biosynthetic process  P
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {
    line = $0;
    gsub(/GO:[0-9]+[ \t]*/, "", line);
    for(i=1; i<=NF && substr($i, 1, 3) == "GO:"; ++i)
      desc[$i] = line;
    next;
  }
  { print $1, $2, desc[$2]; }
' database file
```

The first block executes for the first file only; the second block for the second file only. The first file is the database of codes and descriptions. The description is hashed for each of the GO numbers on the line. For the second file, the descriptions are printed with the other info.

Comment: Hello! When I try to use your code it gives me this error: 'awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 NR==FNR {line = $0 gsub(/GO:[0-9]+[ \t]*/, "", line) >>>  for <<< (i=1; i<=NF && substr($i, 1, 3) == "GO:"; ++i) desc[$i] = line next} { print $1, $2, desc[$2] }
awk: illegal statement at source line 1'

Comment: If you're going to squish the lines together on the same line, you need to add semicolons between the statements. I'll add them in above.

Comment: Wow, that worked quite well! Thanks a lot! Also, there don't seem to be any missing lines in this output, even though the code is kind of similar to the one that @jaypal provided. What would be the big difference, if you have time to explain it to me?

Comment: jaypal processes the files in the opposite order. I think that's the main difference.

Comment: @MPR6 In my code, I was creating a hash map using your file. Since the sequences were repeating, the keys got overwritten hence the hash map only had a subset (unique sequences) in it to do a look up.

Comment: Hmm, this thread turned out to be quite educational thanks to both of you. Again, thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { 
    genes[$2] = $1;
    next
}
{
    line = $0; 
    gsub (/GO:[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*/, "", line); 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in genes) {
            print genes[$i], $i, line;
            next
        }
    }
}
' file database
```

- Create a hash from file first. We use second column as key and first column as value.
- When we have completely loaded the file into memory, we move to the database file for look up.
- We first save the entire line in a variable and remove all `GO` sequences from it.
- We iterate over all fields delimited by space and check if the field is present in our hash. If it does, we print the value of hash which is gene_id. the key that matched which is the `GO:` sequence and the line.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the extremely detailed answer! I just used it and the output looks exactly like what I need, the only thing I noticed is that it has several fewer lines than the input file and so, some are missing (for example, my file starts at gene_id_100000 and the output starts at gene_id_100965) any idea as to what could cause this?

Comment: I find it weird because I looked up some random lines that were missing from the output and their GO is present in the database.

Comment: Already did the edit! Thanks for your time!. The result from wc -l for the file is 61307 and for the output is 2270.

Comment: @MPR6 Did you create these files on windows environment? Are you sure you don't have any special or hidden characters. Do a `cat -vet file` to look for weird characters. I just ran a local test using the data from your question and they worked as you expected. Also, are those `GO:` sequences unique or do they repeat in your file?

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that they repeat quite a bit!. The GO:0000105 (which is one of the ones missing) repeats 123 times. That could be the problem?. Also, I have been working all the time on a mac so I haven't changed environments.